# How to make the user enter an integer and then continue entering new ones until their number is the same as the very first one?

Tags: java

My question is how to write a program which makes the user enter an integer and then  continue entering as many ints as the first int's value?For example the user enters 5 and then has to write 5 more ints(their value is not important) until he writes 5?The language is Java.Thank you! :)

Comment: I mean until he writes 5 integers,not 5 as a digit,my bad

Comment: I have no idea how to do it that is why I am asking

Comment: create int array with length of first input value and iterate over the array and get inputs to that array

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to store the first int the you reading, and move with `loop` from `0` to the first input number. Then, inside the `loop`, you have to do a reading for the next x `ints`.

In my code, I stored the next `ints` inside an `array`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter how much numbers you want to type:");
    count = reader.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[count];
    System.out.println("Enter " + count + " numbers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arr[i] = reader.nextInt();
    }

}
```